# $\lim_{N\to\infty}N(\ln d + q\ln\frac{u}{d})$

Tags: limits

Let $\sigma, r,T>0$ be fixed. Let $u=\exp(\sigma\sqrt{h})$, $d=1/u$, where $h=T/N$. Let $$q=\frac{\exp(rh)-d}{u-d}$$

I need to show that
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}N(\ln d + q\ln\frac{u}{d}) = (r-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2})T $$

So far I've only managed to show that $q\to 1/2$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: How can $N$ be fixed if you're taking a limit over it?

Comment: Sure, edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After wading through all the variables, and setting $n=\sqrt N$ and $t=\sqrt T$, I believe we are trying to evaluate
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\sigma t \left(-2 e^{rt^2/n^2+\sigma 
   t/n}+e^{{2 \sigma  t/n}}+1\right)}{1-e^{{2
   \sigma  t/n}}}.
$$
But by a single application of l'Hopital's rule,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sigma t \left(-2 e^{rt^2/n^2+\sigma 
   t/n}+e^{{2 \sigma  t/n}}+1\right)}{1-e^{{2
   \sigma  t/n}}} = \sigma t,
$$
which would imply that the original limit is infinite.